# Create Dynamic Function Name for Event Listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, event-handling

I have this code for a math game. I have a function for a button which defines the location and then draws the button specified in the callback.

The problem is I can only create one of these, since event listeners are, for some baffling reason, referred to by the function they execute, rather than by some other string name.

Unfortunately this means writing a lot of repetitive code instead. Each function called by the eventListener would only differ by the name of the function for that particular button. How do people work around this problem?  Is there no way to name the function (see: functAnim & functClick) using a string?

```
function factsButton(x, y, doFunction, contentCallback)
{
    var getID = document.getElementById("canvas_1");

    if (getID.getContext)
    {
        var ctx = getID.getContext("2d");

        var btnW = 100;
        var btnH = 100;
        var cx = x - btnW/2;
        var cy = y - btnH/2;
        var left = cx;
        var right = cx + btnW;
        var top = cy;
        var bottom = cy + btnH;

        function functAnim(event)
        {   
            var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
            var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
            var mouseX = mousePos.x;
            var mouseY = mousePos.y;
            if (mouseX >= left
                && mouseX <= right
                && mouseY >= top
                && mouseY <= bottom)
            {
                contentCallback(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, true);

            }
            else
            {
                contentCallback(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, false);
            }

        }

        function functClick(event)
        {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
            var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
            var clickX = mousePos.x;
            var clickY = mousePos.y;
            if (clickX >= left
                && clickX <= right
                && clickY >= top
                && clickY <= bottom)
            {
                doFunction();
                getID.removeEventListener("mousemove", functAnim, false);
                getID.removeEventListener("click", functClick, false);
            }

        }

        contentCallback(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, false);
        getID.addEventListener("click", functClick, false);
        getID.addEventListener("mousemove", functAnim, false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For some reason it wasn't as clear as to what I wanted. I'm not wanting to call the functions by string, but rather create them with dynamic names. For instance, since I need 4 buttons created, I would like to call my function like this: factsButton(50, 50, addClicked, "add"); With "add", instead of "functClick" they could be called "addClick" and "addAnim" or say it was "sub" instead of "add", it would create those events and functions as "subAnim" and "subClick". That way I get 8 separate event listeners each with different "names". Otherwise I end up with only 2 despite having 4 buttons.

Comment: You can name a function by a string and then use `window[stringName]()`, but it would help to see how you use this.

Comment: *"The problem is I can only create one of these, since event listeners are ... referred to by the function they execute, rather than by some other string name."* Why would that keep you from creating several? Are you saying you want to be able to remove all listeners at from `getID` at once? If so, just keep a master Object that holds an Array of functions for each event type, then iterate the Arrays when it's time to remove the lsiteners.

Comment: ...if that's not the problem, then you need to describe *specifically* what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid repetitive code, i.e. making 4 of the functions above with the only difference being the "name" of the event listener.

Comment: See my edits to the post above, maybe that will help explain.

Comment: If you invoke the `factsButton()` function 4 times, you should get 8 different event listeners bound. The event listener system doesn't care what the names are. It only cares that you're binding with a unique set of arguments, where uniqueness of the functions is determined by object identity, not by the name or code of the function.

Comment: ...here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5BJwm/

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your question confuses me for some reason :-\

Anyway,

If you want to call a function by string instead of by function pointer, add your functions as elements in a javascript object.

```
// a javascript object containing function definitions

var myFunctions={

    functAnim: function(event)
        {   
            var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
            var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
            var mouseX = mousePos.x;
            var mouseY = mousePos.y;
            if (mouseX >= left
                && mouseX <= right
                && mouseY >= top
                && mouseY <= bottom)
            {
                contentCallback(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, true);
            }
            else
            {
                contentCallback(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, false);
            }
        },


    functClick: function(event)
    {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
        var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
        var clickX = mousePos.x;
        var clickY = mousePos.y;
        if (clickX >= left
            && clickX <= right
            && clickY >= top
            && clickY <= bottom)
        {
            doFunction();
            getID.removeEventListener("mousemove", functAnim, false);
            getID.removeEventListener("click", functClick, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can call your functions by string.

```
// useage
myFunctions["functAnim"](eventObject);   // calls functAnim
myFunctions["functClick"](eventObject);  // calls functClick
```

Comment: Not sure what is confusing but I'll try to explain further. I'm not wanting to call the functions by string, but rather create them with dynamic names. For instance, since I need 4 buttons created, I would like to call my function like this: factsButton(50, 50, addClicked, "add"); With "add", instead of "functClick" they could be called "addClick" and "addAnim" or say it was "sub" instead of "add", it would create those events and functions as "subAnim" and "subClick". That way I get 8 separate functions with different "names".

Comment: Nevermind, I was apparently misunderstanding how event listeners work when created multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's some 5 years later, and it came in exactly when I needed it the most.